# Flex: Set caret cursor position in RichEditableText control

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, caret, richeditabletext

Is there a method to set the caret position within a RichEditableText control?

The control's contents can contain errors that the user must fix which are navigated though via Next/Previous buttons, and during the navigation I would like to set the caret cursor to the end of each error within the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to change the focus:

textField.[setFocus()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#setFocus%28%29)

Then set the positoin:

textField.[selectRange()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/RichEditableText.html#selectRange%28%29)